# Excel VBA: Transpose data from columns in one Workbook to rows in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, rows, transpose

I am new to VBA.

Transposing data from columns in one Workbook to another as rows is throwing errors. Tried suggestions from Stack Overflow and elsewhere but no success.

> Error Runtime Error 1004 -> PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

**Code:**

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = "C:\trial\"
MyFile = Dir(FilePath)
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
If MyFile = "here.xlsm" Then
Exit Sub
End If
'Opening data.xls to pull data from one column with 2 values (E6 and E7)
Workbooks.Open (FilePath & MyFile), Editable:=True
Dim SourceRange As Range
Set SourceRange = ActiveSheet.Range("E6:E7")
SourceRange.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
'Back to calling file - here.xlsm and pasting both values in single row (for e.g. A2 and B2)
erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Dim targetRange As Range
Set targetRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1)
targetRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: so what is the error?

Comment: Sorry to missed it - Error is on targetRange.PasteSpecial line. Error -> PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

Comment: and what is the actual error message that you are receiving?

Comment: Error Runtime Error 1004 -> PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you cannot do both values only and transpose at the same time.

Try this:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim FilePath As String
Dim swb As Workbook
Dim twb As Workbook

Set twb = ThisWorkbook
FilePath = "C:\trial\"

MyFile = Dir(FilePath)
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If MyFile = "here.xlsm" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Change "Sheet1" below to the actual name of the sheet
    erow = twb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(twb.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    'Opening data.xls to pull data from one column with 2 values (E6 and E7)
    Set swb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & MyFile)
    'assign values
    twb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(erow, 1).Resize(, 2).Value = Application.Transpose(swb.ActiveSheet.Range("E6:E7").Value)
    'close
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. However there is error 438 (Object doesn't support this property or method)         here -     erow = twb.Sheet1.Cells(twb.Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Comment: @Anand try edit.  Change "Sheet1"  to the actual name of the sheet

Comment: OMG that was great help. Thank you so much Scott. Can you please give some clarity in my code (values and transpose same time means ?)

Comment: @Anand when using the pastespecial to transpose it has to paste everything(xlpasteall) not just the values(xlpastvalues) or it errors.  Plus when values are the only thing wanted using the copy/paste method is slower than just assigning the values like I did.

Comment: that was very helpful... really appreciate :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:
Its a simpler example that does same thing
copy/paste method applies only to active objects (like, sheets, ranges, etc)
so you need to activate one, then the other,

```
Sub tst1()
Dim inbook, outbook As Workbook
Dim inSheet, outSheet As Worksheet
Dim inRange, outRange As Range


Set inbook = Application.Workbooks("temp1.xlsx")
Set outbook = Application.Workbooks("temp2.xlsx")

Set inSheet = inbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
Set outSheet = outbook.Worksheets("sheet1")

inSheet.Activate

Set inRange = ActiveSheet.Range("a1:b4")
inRange.Copy

outSheet.Activate
Set outRange = ActiveSheet.Range("a1:d2")
outRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```